# Spark parallelizing flatmap

Tags: apache-spark

I've been recently working with Spark's `flatmap` operator. My current flow is as follows.

```scala
var result = arrayOfData.flatmap(entry => someOperations())(encoder)
```

where encoder for the table of interest is for example

```scala
val schema = getSchema(spark, table)
val schemaStruct = StructType(schema.map(v => convertToStructField(v.fName, v.fType)).toArray)
RowEncoder(schemaStruct)
```

When I'm trying to operate on parallelized data -- an example where `arrayOfData` is a RDD, I'm getting type mismatches. The (encoder) part after flatMap complains with

```
required classTag [Row]
found expressionEncoder [Row]
```

How is this issue normally addressed? Seems that without being able to convert to classTag[Row] this operation cannot be performed?